# ClassNotFoundException:OracleDriver in JDBC connectivity

Tags: java, database, classnotfoundexception

`ClassNotFoundException:OracleDriver` in JDBC connectivity with Oracle 11g express db on Win7 32-bit

The source code is here:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.sql.*;

class OracleCon{
public static void main(String args[])
   {
        try{
              Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
              Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
              "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","ashish");
               Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");
             while(rs.next())
               System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));
              con.close();
             }catch(Exception e)
                      { 
                         System.out.println(e);
                       }
      }
}
```

Before running this program code, I set path by using following commands:

```
path c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin 
set classpath=c:\program fles\Java\jre7\lib\ojdbc14
```

When I was running this source code by cmd (command Prompt), I got following output:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Comment: You need to add the jdbc connector jar. Get it from there and put the jar in your classpath http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..` 3) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. ..

Comment: .. 4) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: When adding jar files to the classpath you have to specify the name of the jar.  You cannot specify the name of the directory containing the jar.